# Profiler: Live Object View doesn't show all packages

Tags: apache-flex, air, flexbuilder, flash-builder

I'm throwing a hail mary out here, has anyone found that only a very small subset of known loaded classes / instances are running but for some reason the live object view does not show the full extent?

This doesn't have anything to do with filtering, I've even removed the normal spark/mx/flash star.star to no affect. This is an AIR application, but an overwhelming majority of our project code is not AIR specific.

To the extent of what the Profiler is aware of, it reports a total runtime of about 1.5Mb, to which SystemTotal is actually 20-25Mb. Obviously, traces are indicating that the appropriate amount of constructors are being called.

I've tried:

1. Promoting variable references to class members thinking function scope might be hiding the 'new'
2. Declaring class members public.
3. Upgraded to FlashBuilder 4.7, AIR 3.1 - same effect

The profiler is "somewhat" aware that something is there, since many instances are held in Arrays / Hashtables in a RobotLegs framework: ie the mappings array of the Injector is the correct length when viewed in the Object References view, but go to open it to inspect its properties and it's blank other than the fully qualified class name.

This is highly frustrating since I know a gigantor chunk of memory is being swallowed in one particular area, but this is completely walled off.

Fixes?